# Where to get data for code chunks?

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to construct a document using R, Latex, and **knitr**. When I try to include a plot using `qplot` using code chunks I get an error message saying `error object 'circuitdf' not found`. I have been working on getting the basic dataframe to work in the console window and the `qplot` window works just fine with the dataframe I built. I am wondering if I need to call the dataframe for the code chunk to execute?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a simple test document.

<<"circuit, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE">>=
library(ggplot2)
qplot(current, voltage, data=circuitdf) + geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)
@


\end{document}
```

Comment: Where's `circuitdf` in this code? The knitr document has to be **complete** code.

Comment: you might be working with RStudio, although you did not mention your editor; in that case, your objects in the console are independent of the knitr document; RStudio opens a new R session to compile your document to make sure the document is reproducible by itself

Comment: BTW, why did you quote the chunk header? I mean `""` in `<<>>=` is unnecessary.